# Maven assembly: generate a resource zip file and include it into the main assembly zip file

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

How can I proceed to include a generated zip file into a *main* zip file with the Maven Assembly plugin?

For example, I have the following folder structure:

```
./folderA/
./file1
```

and I want to generate a zip file where the content is like this:

```
folderA.zip
file1
```

---

Here my simplified config':

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project >
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly-zipFolderA.xml</descriptor>
                    <finalName>folderA.zip</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    <finalName>${module-zipFinalName}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**assembly-zipFolderA.xml**

```
<assembly>
    <id>folderA-zip</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>folderA</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**assembly.xml**

```
<assembly>
    <id>main</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <files>
        <file>
            <source>file1</source>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>folderA.zip</source>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

---

**===>** with this config, Maven complains that it can't find *folderA.zip*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't declare the plugin twice; instead, you need to declare two executions of the `maven-assembly-plugin`.

The first execution will create the first assembly and then, the second execution will use this assembly to create the final one. Both of those executions will be bound to the `package` phase, and Maven will invoke the plugin's execution [in the order of declaration in the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins).

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-folderA</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly-zipFolderA.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>folderA</finalName> <!-- name without extension -->
                <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>${module-zipFinalName}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

A couple of notes:

- The `<finalName>` should not contain the extension, so a `finalName` of `folderA` will produce the archive `folderA.zip` after the ZIP assembly is made.
- The first assembly will be created inside the build directory, which is `target` by default. As such, the second one needs to reference it there with:

  ```
  <file>
      <source>${project.build.directory}/folderA.zip</source>
  </file>
  ```

  in its assembly descriptor.
- Since the first assembly is not the final one, you probably don't want it attached, i.e. as an additional artifact produced by your project. You can disable this by setting [`attach`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#attach) to `false`. This will make sure only the last final one is considered when deploying or releasing.
- [`descriptor`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptor) is a deprecated parameter, you should use [`descriptors`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptors) instead.

With such a configuration, running `mvn clean package` will produce the correct archive inside the build folder.

Comment: Concerning the finalName it was a wrong copy-paste :-)
Btw I've applied your solution but i got
`Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found`
:-/

Comment: @gudepier Well, do both `assembly-zipFolderA.xml` and `assembly.xml` exists? I tested locally with sample files without issue. They should be located at the basedir according to your post (next to the POM).

Comment: yes the both exist well close my pom.xml; i even changed the file spelling in case of the dash isn't supported but i get the same...

Comment: @gudepier How are you launching Maven? You should just launch `mvn clean package` to have the result. If you're using `mvn assembly:single` the error is expected then.

Comment: my Master pom was the problem, it already defines an execution block, now it's working better >_>
thks

Comment: Any idea how I can deploy just the final zip and not the folderA.zip?